# vertical-align property not working on google chrome

Tags: html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table,td {border:1px solid black ;}
            table {width : 80% ;height:80%;}
            .top {vertical-align:top};
            .center {vertical-align: middle};
            .bottom {vertical-align: bottom};
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td class = "top">1</td><td class = "top" "left">2</td><td class = "top" "left">3</td></tr>
                <tr><td class = "center" >4</td><td class = "center">5</td><td class = "center">6</td></tr>
                <tr><td class = "bottom">7</td><td class = "bottom">8</td><td class = "bottom">9</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Line number 8 ie `.bottom {vertical-align: bottom};` is working perfectly fine in internet explorer 8 but it does not work on google chrome even though i have the latest version.

Comment: You have an error in the class definition for the first td.

Answer (score 5):

I think you had a simple syntax issue, the semi-colons should be inside the closing bracket.

See your code below.

Also, add `height: 100%` to `body` and `html` to set the reference for the table-cell heights.

Note: As noted in one of the posted comments, you did not define a CSS style for `left`, so it was not clear what you intended. By itself, `left` is not a valid attribute.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
.top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.center {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="top">1</td>
      <td class="top">2</td>
      <td class="top">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="center">4</td>
      <td class="center">5</td>
      <td class="center">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bottom">7</td>
      <td class="bottom">8</td>
      <td class="bottom">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```